# Prove that determinant involving angles of triangle is purely real

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $A, B, C$ are the angles of a triangle, prove that

$$ \begin{vmatrix} e^{2iA} & e^{-iC} & e^{-iB} \\\ e^{-iC} & e^{2iB} & e^{-iA} \\\ e^{-iB} & e^{-iA} & e^{2iC} \end{vmatrix}$$

is purely real.

---

I tried solving this question, even by expanding the matrix directly. But in the end, I get terms of the form $ e^{i(f(A, B, C))} $ from which I am unable to converge. Is this because I haven't studied complex numbers deeply yet?

---

*Note: This question originates from SK Goyal's book in Algebra for JEE and other competitive exams in India.*

---

Comment: You probably need Euler's formula .

Comment: You are talking about the determinant of this matrix, yes? And is the $(2, 3)$th entry meant to be $e^{-iA}$ rather than $e^{iA}$?

Comment: Yes. Your're correct, I've edited the question. Sorry for any confusions, it is actually a new topic for me right now.

Comment: Looks like you know how to solve the question, please answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly expanding the determinant, we get
$$ e^{2iA + 2iB + 2iC} + 2e^{-iA -iB -iC} - 3$$
and since $A + B + C = \pi$, this determinant is equal to
$$ e^{2 \pi i} + 2 e^{-i \pi} - 3 = 1 - 2 - 3 = -4.$$

Comment: Looks like the problem with me was that I haven't studied complex numbers deeply yet. I didn't know that $ e^{2i\pi}, e^{-i\pi} $ have a real value.

Comment: You should learn about the polar form of complex numbers, and Euler's formula, which says that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study that!

Answer (score 0):

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} e^{2iA} & e^{-iC} & e^{-iB} \\\ e^{-iC} & e^{2iB} & e^{-iA} \\\ e^{-iB} & e^{-iA} & e^{2iC} \end{bmatrix} = e^{-i(A+B+C)}\left(2-3e^{i(A+B+C)}+e^{3i(A+B+C)}\right)$$

but $A+B+C = \pi$ then $ e^{-i(A+B+C)}\left(2-3e^{i(A+B+C)}+e^{3i(A+B+C)}\right) = -4$